# imported font with face-font doesn't work in svg

Tags: css, svg, fonts

I have a problem with my angular-App.

**Demo of the problem**: https://plnkr.co/edit/gkGNW2WucQrhUBmW5y6M?p=preview

**Edit 3:**
The font was installed in my pc. Maybe it's why I had the svg-working with Montserrat in the plunker.

I have imported the font Montserrat the normal way for the pages.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500');
```

But when i work on my svg file with the font Montserrat, i have at the end, a svg-file with:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .st3{font-family:'Montserrat-Regular';}
    .st6{font-family:'Montserrat-Medium';}
</style>
```

So i have done the following in my styles.scss:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';font-weight: 400;src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v10/zhcz-_WihjSQC0oHJ9TCYPk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2) format('woff2');}
```

When i use:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular'
```

it works in my pages. But **it doesn't work on my SVG**.

When i overwrite my svg file by:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .st3{font-family:'Montserrat';font-weight:400}
    .st6{font-family:'Montserrat';font-weight:500}
</style>
```

it works.

But is it possible to not Overwrite and to use the font-family 'Montserrat-Regular' ?

**Edit 1:**

In Chrome,

- when I change the normal font of h1,h2,p,... to Montserrat-Medium, it works.
- When I change the font in the SVG to Montserrat, it works.

So I don't understand where the problem come from.

**Edit 2:**

**here is a Demo:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/gkGNW2WucQrhUBmW5y6M?p=preview

Comment: So if you are unable to change the font-family name in the SVG to 'Montserrat', which is what Google sets as the name, you could create a font alias (see https://www.zachleat.com/web/rename-font/). Not entirely sure if that’s what you’re asking about, but hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, with " local('Montserrat') " in @font-face, it changes nothing. I dont get the font Montserrat.

Comment: Hmm, could you post a JSBin or Codepen example? That will help a lot.

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/gkGNW2WucQrhUBmW5y6M?p=preview

Comment: I have noticed that the plnkr was working with my first computer but not in my laptop. Strange.

Comment: The "SVG working" line in your plunkr is not working for me.  Do you have Montserrat font installed on your computer by any chance?  It might explain why it is working for you in the SVG on only one computer.

Comment: Yes, it was installed, you are probably right. So the problem is now: Why is the font Montserrat not in the SVG?

Comment: You need to include the `@font-face` etc in your SVG. The CSS applied to the HTML cannot be seen by the external SVG.

Comment: Ah, I think @PaulLeBeau is correct. I was thinking your SVG was inlined on the page, in which case it would inherit the other styles.

Comment: Yes this is right. Thanks everyone.